# Wrong files' paths in php project

Tags: php

This is structure of my php project

[image]

Files **index.php** and **config.php** are located in root folder.

In **config.php** file I define path to libs folder

```
<?php 

DEFINE('LIBS', 'app/Libs/');
```

This is **index.php** folder

```
<?php 

require 'config.php';

function __autoload($class) {
        require LIBS. $class. ".php";
    }

$bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
$bootstrap->init();

//Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

This is **Bootstrap.php** file

```
<?php 

class Bootstrap {
private $_url = null;
private $_controller = null;

private $_controllerPath = '/../controllers/';
private $_modelPath = 'models/';
private $_errorFile = 'error.php';
private $_defaultFile = 'home.php';

public function init(){
    $this->_parseUrl();

    if(empty($this->_url[0])){
        $this->_loadDefaultController();
        return false;
    }   

    $this->_loadExistingController();
    $this->_callControllerMethod(); 
}

private function _parseUrl(){
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $this->_url = explode('/', $url);
}

private function _loadDefaultController() {
    require $this->_controllerPath . $this->_defaultFile;
    $this->_controller = new Home();
    $this->_controller->index();    
}

private function _loadExistingController() {
    $file = $this->_controllerPath . $this->_url[0] . '.php';
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
        $this->_controller = new $this->_url[0];
        $this->_controller->loadModel($this->_url[0], $this->_modelPath);   
    } else {
        $this->_error();
        return false;
    }           
}

private function _callControllerMethod() {
    if(isset($this->_url[2])) {
        if(method_exists($this->_controller, $this->_url[1])) {
            $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}($this->_url[2]);
        } else {
            $this->_error();
        }
    } else {
        if(isset($this->_url[1])) {
            if(method_exists($this->_controller, $this->_url[1])) {
                $this->_controller->{$this->_url[1]}();
            } else {
                $this->_error();
            }
        } else {
            $this->_controller->index();
        }
    }
}

private function _error() {
    require $this->_controllerPath . $this->_errorFile;
    $this->_controller = new Error();
    $this->_controller->index();
    exit;
}

}
```

The problem is, `Bootstrap` class detects Home controller the right way, but it doesn't find other controllers, e.g. user controller, and tries to use error controller, but doesn't find error index view.

```
Warning: require(/../views/error/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\libs\View.php on line 9

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/../views/error/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\libs\View.php on line 9
```

I guess it's something wrong with paths, but I don't know how to fix it. How to make Bootstrap find other controllers? Maybe I should change project structure? It's my first attemt to create something so I'm just trying to figure it out.

Comment: do you mean ` $_controllerPath = '../controllers/';`?

Comment: No, in this case bootstrap doesn't find any controller, include Home controller. Warning: require(../controllers/home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\libs\Bootstrap.php on line 48

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../controllers/home.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\libs\Bootstrap.php on line 48

Comment: On Unix the filenames are not case-sensitive, but in windows they do. Change `home.php` to `Home.php`

Comment: Error is the same Warning: require(../controllers/Home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\libs\Bootstrap.php on line 48

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../controllers/Home.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\libs\Bootstrap.php on line 48

Comment: @Federico it is the other way around in *nix the file names are case-sensitive and windows they are not.

Comment: where's the 48° line?

Comment: Method `_loadDefaultController` require $this->_controllerPath . $this->_defaultFile;

Comment: change it to `require __DIR__ . $this->_controllerPath . $this->_defaultFile;`

Comment: @bansi, are you sure about that? perhaps my memory is bad, sorry

Comment: `require __DIR__ . $this->_controllerPath . $this->_defaultFile;` works for Home controller, but doesn't work for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating a new project and already use composer, it could be good for you to follow the specification for autoloading of [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). No need for you to implements your autoloader. With composer you can even use the [classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) to define autoloading for a project that don't follows PSR-0/4. But the classmap autoloading is simply there for old legacy codebases, if your start a new project you *should* follow PSR-0/4.

---

Said that, what you can change on your current code:

Change

```
DEFINE('LIBS', '/app/Libs/');
```

to

```
define('LIBS', __DIR__ . '/app/Libs/');
```

`__DIR__` is a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), in this case represents the absolute path of the directory of `config.php`. My advice is not to rely ever to relative path. For the same reason change

```
require $this->_controllerPath . $this->_defaultFile;
// and
require $this->_controllerPath . $this->_errorFile;
// and
$file = $this->_controllerPath . $this->_url[0] . '.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__ . $this->_controllerPath . $this->_defaultFile;
// and
require __DIR__ . $this->_controllerPath . $this->_errorFile;
// and 
$file = __DIR__ . $this->_controllerPath . $this->_url[0] . '.php';
```

Comment: I used you solution `define('LIBS', __DIR__ . '/app/Libs/');`, and it works fine with controllers, but instead I've got a new problem with css files on other pages (on home page it's ok). I add css file in `header.php` file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/font-awesome.min.css">` but on user index page there are errors http://i.imgur.com/i61syDQ.png it seems like project tries to include them like controller http://i.imgur.com/nCkIwZ4.png

Comment: share your `.htaccess` file

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
Options -Indexes`

Comment: can you add `Options -MultiViews`? If it doesn't work, try also `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: I've just tried but problems with css files the same.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should already do that job... try with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js)$`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help.

Comment: are you sure that `/project/user/public/css/font-awesome.min.css` exists? isn't `/project/public/css/font-awesome.min.css`?

Comment: css files exist and are located in `project/public/css/%filename%.css`

Comment: but in your screen you call `/project/user/public/css/%filename%.css`

Comment: add `<base href="/project/" />` in your page header

Comment: Yes, and I don't know why. I add them like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.min.css">`

Comment: @Heidel, because even those are relative url

Comment: `<base href="/project/" />` solved the problem with css files, but it seems like duck tape

Comment: then call `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/project/public/css/style.min.css">` instead and remove `base`. My advice is the same: don't use relative url/path

Comment: Maybe I should use other project structure?

Comment: Yep, I know, but it's my first attempt to create something so I'm not sure about how to do that

Comment: I know about this tutorial but since I newbie there are a lot of things difficult to understand there